# madlib cannot start on openshift

Tags: openshift, madlib

I'm trying to deploy madlib on openshift, but without success.
I've deployed the provided image from docker hub, but it fails to start, missing the compilation step:

```
CONTAINER_NAME=my_madlib IMAGE_TAG=LaTex ./tool/docker_start.sh
```

If possible to deploy madlib on openshift ?
If so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

madlib supports Greenplum and Postgres only at this point